# How do I transfer a NFT from a wallet to another using Taquito?

Tags: node, taquito

I want to transfer one collectible from one wallet to another using Taquito (I know how to do the operation manually using a wallet, but not in code).

The documentation shows how to transfer an amount of tez, but not a NFT:
https://tezostaquito.io/docs/making_transfers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For FA2 transfers you can have a look at: https://tezostaquito.io/docs/fa2_parameters

Example: (For NFT's, amount is `1`)

```
import { TezosToolkit } from "@taquito/taquito";

const Tezos = await new TezosTooolkit(RPC_URL);
const contract = await Tezos.wallet.at(FA2_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);

const transfer_params = [
    {
        from_: "tz1VSUr8wwNhLAzempoch5d6hLRiTh8Cjcjb",
        txs: [
                {
                    to_: "tz1aSkwEot3L2kmUvcoxzjMomb9mvBNuzFK6",
                    token_id: 0,
                    amount: 11111
                },
                {
                    to_: "tz1aSkwEot3L2kmUvcoxzjMomb9mvBNuzFK6",
                    token_id: 1,
                    amount: 22222
                },
                {
                    to_: "tz1Me1MGhK7taay748h4gPnX2cXvbgL6xsYL",
                    token_id: 0,
                    amount: 333333
                }
        ]
    }
]

const op = await contract.methods.transfer(transfer_params).send();
await op.confirmation();
```

For FA1.2: https://assets.tqtezos.com/docs/token-contracts/fa12/2-fa12-ligo